# Error running flutter project after flutter 2.5.1 upgrade

Tags: flutter

/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filepicker_windows-2.0.0/lib/src/filedialog.dart:134:58: Error: The argument type 'Pointer<Pointer>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Pointer<Pointer>'.

- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
- 'NativeType' is from 'dart:ffi'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.0/lib/src/combase.dart').
  hr = knownFolderManager.GetFolder(publicMusicFolder, ppkf);
  ^
  /C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filepicker_windows-2.0.0/lib/src/opendialog.dart:116:33: Error: The argument type 'Pointer<Pointer>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Pointer<Pointer>'.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
- 'NativeType' is from 'dart:ffi'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.0/lib/src/combase.dart').
  hr = fileDialog.GetResult(ppsi);
  ^
  /C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/filepicker_windows-2.0.0/lib/src/savedialog.dart:85:33: Error: The argument type 'Pointer<Pointer>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Pointer<Pointer>'.
- 'Pointer' is from 'dart:ffi'.
- 'NativeType' is from 'dart:ffi'.
- 'COMObject' is from 'package:win32/src/combase.dart' ('/C:/Users/admin/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/win32-2.3.0/lib/src/combase.dart').
  hr = fileDialog.GetResult(ppsi);
  ^

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.